# Añadir margin en columnas de bootstrap sin que se descuadre

Tags: css, bootstrap

Buenas, tengo un problema con Bootstrap.

Tengo 3 columnas a las cuales les pongo un background y un border para hacerlas más atractivas, pero una vez se lo pongo, estas se descolocan pues cambia su ancho total, por lo que la última pasa a la fila de abajo.

Este es el ejemplo del que hablo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y lo que yo intento hacer es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo html:

```
    <div id="cols3" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Discomovil Valencia. Bodas, Noche Vieja y Fiestas</h2>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/discomovil.jpg" alt="">
                    <p>Ofrecemos diferentes formatos de discomoviles en Valencia, sonorizaciones y espectáculos, adaptándonos a las necesidades de cada cliente y cada evento, nuestra oferta es válida tipos tanto para interiores como exteriores, letras e iniciales para bodas con luz</p>
                    <button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Audiovisiales para Empresas Sonido para eventos</h2>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/microfono.jpg" alt="">
                    <p>Realizamos servicios de megafonia, montaje de congresos y sonorizaciones en general. Para ello disponemos de unidades de hasta 12.000w de sonido D.A.S estacado y nuevos formatos line array NEXO de hasta 16.000w. materiales de primera calidad y Linea.</p>
                    <button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Alquiler de Altavoces. Proyectores y Efectos y más</h2>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/alquiler.jpg" alt="">
                    <p>Alquiler de pantallas y proyectores, altavoces y equipos de música , mesas de sonido digitales, microfonos inalámbricos, efectos de iluminación, equipamiento Dj, Equipos Pioneer, karaoke, máquinas de burbujas, máquinas de humo, laser, banderas, tarimas, escenarios..</p>
                    <button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y este es el código css respecto a esas columnas

```
#cols3 .col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #EFEDF1;
    border: 1px solid #E2E3E8;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para conseguir eso tienes que meterlo en otro contenedor `div` y ahí darle los márgenes deseados:

```
<div class="col-md-4">                
    <div class="nuevo-estilo"><!-- !!! -->
        <h2>Discomovil Valencia. Bodas, Noche Vieja y Fiestas</h2>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/discomovil.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Ofrecemos diferentes formatos de discomoviles en Valencia, sonorizaciones y espectáculos, adaptándonos a las necesidades de cada cliente y cada evento, nuestra oferta es válida tipos tanto para interiores como exteriores, letras e iniciales para bodas con luz</p>
        <button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
    </div>                     
</div>
```

```css
.nuevo-estilo {
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: #EFEDF1;
    border: 1px solid #E2E3E8;
    padding: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">                
<div class="nuevo-estilo">
<h2>Discomovil Valencia. Bodas, Noche Vieja y Fiestas</h2>
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/discomovil.jpg" alt="">
<p>Ofrecemos diferentes formatos de discomoviles en Valencia, sonorizaciones y espectáculos, adaptándonos a las necesidades de cada cliente y cada evento, nuestra oferta es válida tipos tanto para interiores como exteriores, letras e iniciales para bodas con luz</p>
<button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
</div>                     
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">                  
<div class="nuevo-estilo">
<h2>Audiovisiales para Empresas Sonido para eventos</h2>
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/microfono.jpg" alt="">
<p>Realizamos servicios de megafonia, montaje de congresos y sonorizaciones en general. Para ello disponemos de unidades de hasta 12.000w de sonido D.A.S estacado y nuevos formatos line array NEXO de hasta 16.000w. materiales de primera calidad y Linea.</p>
<button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
</div>                    
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">                  
<div class="nuevo-estilo">
<h2>Alquiler de Altavoces. Proyectores y Efectos y más</h2>
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/alquiler.jpg" alt="">
<p>Alquiler de pantallas y proyectores, altavoces y equipos de música , mesas de sonido digitales, microfonos inalámbricos, efectos de iluminación, equipamiento Dj, Equipos Pioneer, karaoke, máquinas de burbujas, máquinas de humo, laser, banderas, tarimas, escenarios..</p>
<button class="buttonN">Saber más</button>
</div>                    
</div>                  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Y sabrías explicarme el por qué ? Así lo entiendo mejor.

Comment: @Rodrypaladin - Claro... Al meterlo en otro contenedor y darle estilo al mismo no _rompes_ el grid de bootstrap... así de simple :)

Comment: @Rodrypaladin si te ha servido ¿por qué no aceptas la respuesta?

Comment: No me di ni cuenta!

Answer (score 0):

Yo entiendo mejor el código si lo codifico de esta manera:

```
    <div class="row p-1">
        <%-- fechas  --%>
        <div class="col-4 p-1">
            <div class="border p-3 m-1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Elegir fechas:" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%-- país  --%>
        <div class="col-4 p-1">
            <div class="border p-3 m-1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Elegir país:" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 p-1">
            <div class="border p-3 m-1">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Elegir contraparte:" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En el row pongo el margen que queremos que quede alrededor de las tres columnas. En cada col pongo el padding de esa columna. Y dentro de cada col pongo un div que me permite elegir el margen y el padding.

Así se entiende que los col dividen el espacio del row en tantas partes como quiero y que con el div interno seleccionamos margen y padding de esa área.